# jQuery wait for if statement to finish

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two if statements in javascript. I need the second if statement to run only after the first if statement is executed (I cannot have the two if statements inside each other, as the first one executes sometimes. Otherway, the first one has to be checked before the second could run.)

How do i do this?

Here is the code btw:

```
    if( $('#suggestion-'+change).html() == null )
    {       
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/suggestion/ajax-change/',
            data: {type: change},
            success: function(result,status)
            {
                $('#profile_suggestion .content_wrapper').prepend(result);
            }
        });
    }

    if( active != change )
    {
        var panelShow = '#suggestion-' + change;
        var panelHide = '#suggestion-' + active;
        var dirShow = ''; var dirHide = '';

        switch( active )
        {
            case 'compatibility':
                dirHide = 'left';
                switch( change )
                {
                    case 'mutual':
                        dirShow = 'right';
                        break;
                }
            case 'mutual':
                switch( change )
                {
                    case 'compatibility':
                        dirHide = 'right';
                        dirShow = 'left';
                }
        }
        $(panelHide).hide("slide", { direction: dirHide }, 1000);
        $(panelShow).show("slide", { direction: dirShow }, 1000).removeClass('fader');
        $(panelHide).addClass('fader');
        active = change;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `async: false` to the ajax call.

Comment: It should be async, did you copy my typo? :)

Comment: aysnc AJAX calls are bad news bears.

Comment: i think you mean "sync AJAX" calls are bad news, as well as oxymorons.

Answer (score 1):

You have a misunderstanding of callbacks and asynchronous code.

You'll want to place 2nd if statement into the success callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    url: '/suggestion/ajax-change/',
    data: {
        type: change
    },
    success: function(result, status) {
        $('#profile_suggestion .content_wrapper').prepend(result);
        if (active != change) {
            var panelShow = '#suggestion-' + change;
            var panelHide = '#suggestion-' + active;
            var dirShow = '';
            var dirHide = '';
            .....
        }
    }
});​
```

Because an `xhr` (ajax) request has no specified amount of time to respond you cannot accurately guess when to run another block of code in accoradance to it's response.  You must execute the code in a completed callback, in this case `success`.

Rather than placing the actual code for the 2nd if statement into the success, you should consider placing into another function.

Comment: The ajax does not need to be called all the time! So I wanted to keep the two if statements separately, as to prevent an extra call to ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, can you make the second one into a function and call it upon success? I am sorry if I misunderstood your question..

Or you can do this

```
   $("something").bind('update', function() { do something you want to do });

   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: '/suggestion/ajax-change/',
        data: {type: change},
        success: function(result,status)
        {
            $('#profile_suggestion .content_wrapper').prepend(result);
        },
        complete: function() 
        {
            $("something").trigger('update');
         }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The two if statements are independent of each other, so they cannot be within each other. Its just that the second if statement has to run after the first statement (and sometimes the first if statement is false anyways, but still that needs to be checked first!)

Comment: you can also consider using complete.. and use trigger() to cause a proper event to be generated.